# Sorting csv columns

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, csv

I am trying to sort all columns of a csv file using python. Some files get sorted using this -

```
reader = csv.reader(open("merged.csv"))
        sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
```

But other files give a list index out of range error. I have checked all these files and they all contain the same fields. What could be the reason and a possible solution?